# In an experiment testing catalyst influence on reaction, is NaOH a reactant or a catalyst?

Tags: catalysis

I have recently completed an experiment with hydrogen peroxide (5%), 0.1M KI and 1M NaOH.

Is the sodium hydroxide a reactant or a catalyst in this experiment?

Answer (score 2):

In basic solution the half reactions are:

Reduction:

$\ce{H2O2 + 2 e- -> 2 OH-}$

Oxidation:

$\ce{I- + 6 OH- -> IO3- + 3 H2O + 6 e-}$

So the overall reaction is

$\ce{3 H2O2 + I- -> IO3- + 3 H2O}$

thus $\ce{OH-}$ is overall neither a reactant nor a product. Hence it is either a catalyst, an inhibitor, or a spectator ion.